# Reduction of duplicate words prior to uppercase or lowercase

Tags: java

Main

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                     
     System.out.println(Dupe.Eliminate("Testing UppeR and loweR"));                                                                                                         
     System.out.println(Dupe.Eliminate("UppeR is BetteR"));                                                                         

  }                                     
}
```

Class

```
public class Dupe                                       
{                                       
  public static String Eliminate(String input)                                      
  {                                     
    char[] chrArray = input.toCharArray();                                      
    String letter ="";                                      

    for (char value:chrArray){                                      
      if (letter.indexOf(value) == -1){                                     
        letter += value;                                        
      }                                     
    }                                       
    return letter;                                      
  }                                     
}
```

I am trying to eliminate duplicate letters e.g. Hello would be Helo. Which I have achieved, however, what I want to implement is that it won't matter if it's uppercase or lowercase, it will still be classed as a duplicate so Hehe would be He, not Heh. Should I .equals... each individual letter or is there an efficient way? sorry for asking if it's simple question for you guys.

Comment: Shouldn't Hehe become he?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry typo

Comment: Do you want the duplicate letters to be removed in each word, or in the entire sentence? (i.e. for `"Foo foolish"` do you want `"Foo lish"` or `"Fo folish"`?)

Comment: Easiest way, if not very efficient: `if (letter.toLowerCase().indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(value)) == -1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this. This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but you can try this.

```
  public class Main                                       
  {                                       
     public static void main(String[] args)                                        
     {                                     
        System.out.println(Dupe.Eliminate("Testing UppeR and loweR"));                                                                                                                                                                           

     }                                     
  }

  class Dupe                                       
  {                                       
     public static String Eliminate(String input)                                      
     {                                     
       char[] chrArray = input.toCharArray();                                      
       String letter ="";                                
       for(int index = 0; index < chrArray.length; index++)
       {
           int j = 0;
           boolean flag = true;
          //this while loop is used to check if the next character is already existed in the string (ignoring the uppercase or lowercase)
           while(j < letter.length())
           {
               if((int)chrArray[index] == letter.charAt(j) || (int)chrArray[index] == ((int)letter.charAt(j)+32) ) //32 is because the difference between the ascii value of the uppercase and lowercase letter is 32
               {
                   flag = false;
                   break;
               }
               else
                   j++;
           }

          if(flag == true)
          {
            letter += chrArray[index];
          }
      }

      return letter;                                      
    }                                     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have 2 checks in place with upper case and lower case characters:

```
public static String Eliminate(String input)                                      
{                                     
char[] chrArray = input.toCharArray();                                      
String letter ="";                                      

for (char value:chrArray){                                      
  if (letter.indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) == -1 && letter.indexOf(value.toUpperCase()) == -1){                                     
    letter += value;                                        
  }                                     
}                                       
return letter;                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this will replace all duplicate characters no matter how many in the sequence.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String duped = "aaabbccddeeffgg";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1+");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(duped);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println("Duplicate character " + (duped = duped.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1))));
}
```

If you are looking for duplicates like: `abacd` to replace both a's, try this as the regex given in `Pattern.compile(".*([0-9A-Za-z])\\1+.*")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (stateful) way to do it:-

```
String s = "Hehe";
Set<String> found = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
String result = s.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> "" + (char) c)
        .filter(found::add)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `He`